# RCP: addSelectionChangedListener method loses the view called

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have added an addSelectionChangedListener method to open a new window when a node on the first window is selected. 
It works fine  - a new window is opened. But on the original window, the view from where I make the selection on the tree viewer blanks out.
Any insight is appreciated much.
Thank you!

Comment: Your use of `addSelectionChangedListener` sounds a little peculiar. Could you please a code fragment so we can see what exactly goes on?